# Файл со всеми используемыми модулями для Python

Tags: python

Писал программу на Python, использовал в ней разные модули типа `selenium` и `pandas`. Скопировал с гита всё на другой ПК и не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы все используемые модули автоматически установились? В некоторых языках (типа JS) есть отдельные файлы, куда пишутся все библиотеки, которые исп. в работе. Но как это сделать в Python?
Пока что руками всё устанавливаю, есть способ оптимизации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно создать файл `requirements.txt` со всеми библиотеками и их зависимостями, которые Вы используете в своём проекте. [`requirements.txt`](https://towardsdatascience.com/requirements-vs-setuptools-python-ae3ee66e28af) тоже нужно добавить в гит

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Чтобы установить все зависимости проекта в другом месте

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```